# Haskell : Increment index in a loop

Tags: loops, haskell, indexing

I have a function that calculates f(n) in Haskell. 
I have to write a loop so that it will start calculating values from f(0) to f(n), and will every time compare the value of f(i) with some fixed value. 
I am an expert in OOP, hence I am finding it difficult to think in the functional way. 
For example, I have to write something like

```
while (number < f(i)) 
   i++
```

How would I write this in Haskell?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://learnyouahaskell.com/recursion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that's weird from a functional approach is that it's unclear what the result of your computation is. Do you care about the final result of `f (i)`? Perhaps you care about `i` itself. Without side effects everything neends to have a value.

Let's assume you want the final value of the function `f (i)` as soon as some comparison fails. You can simulate your own while loops using recursion and guards!

```
while :: Int -> Int -> (Int -> Int) -> Int
while start number f
  | val >= number = val
  | otherwise = while (start + 1) number f
    where
      val = f start
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard approach here is

1. Create an infinite list containing all values of f(n).
2. Search this list until you find what you're after.

For example,

```
takeWhile (number <) $ map f [0..]
```

If you *want* to give up after you reach "n", you can easily add that as a separate step:

```
takeWhile (number <) $ take n $ map f [0..]
```

or, alternatively,

```
takeWhile (number <) $ map f [0 .. n]
```

You can do all sorts of other filtering, grouping and processing in this way. But it requires a mental shift. It's a bit like the difference between writing a for-loop to search a table, versus writing an SQL query. Think about Haskell as a bit like SQL, and you'll usually see how to structure your code.

Comment: Thank you. But from what I know, takeWhile takes a list and then creates another by checking for a condition.I do not have a list. f(n) is a function. How can I use it then?

Comment: The `map` function creates this list for you. Or, more exactly, `[0..]` is an infinite list of numbers, and `map f [0..]` applies `f` to every element of that list, producing a list of result that you can then search.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the list of the `i`s such that `f i` is larger than your number:

```
[ i | i<-[0..] , f i > number ]
```

Then, you can simply take the first one, if that's all you want:

```
head [ i | i<-[0..] , f i > number ]
```

Often, many idiomatic loops in imperative programming can be rephrased as list comprehensions, or expressed through `map, filter, foldl, foldr`. In the general case, when the loop is more complex, you can always exploit recursion instead.

Keep in mind that a "blind" translation from imperative to functional programming will often lead to non-idiomatic, hard-to-read code, as it would be the case when translating in the opposite direction. Still, I find it relieving that such translation is always possible.

If you are new to functional programming, I would advise against learning it by translating what you know about imperative programming. Rather, start from scratch following a good book ([LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) is a popular choice).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of explicit recursion, you can use `until` e.g.

```
findGreaterThan :: (Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int -> (Int, Int)
findGreaterThan f init max = until (\(v, i) -> v >= max) (\(v, i) -> (f v, i + 1)) (init, 0)
```

this returns a pair containing the first value to fail the condition and the number of iterations of the given function.